# Nuget package installation error: Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v3

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

```
Install-Package : Unable to load the service index for source 
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.Pow 
   erShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: It sounds like your NuGet configuration is slightly off - is there any reason it's configured for a "curated feed" like that? (It doesn't look like it's anything to do with the Google.Apis.Drive.v3 feed itself.)

Comment: Please always use the code tool to format logs - dumping them in a post without formatting isn't very readable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I did solve my question at last. I did changed my internet proxy address and for that following problem I faced. When I changed proxy address of computer (Go to Settings->Proxy->off use proxy and solve the problem).